# Targeting different APIs for contextual menu

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I returned to reading this book today after finishing my simple program and publishing it, and I stopped on chapter 18 which is about context menus, anyways I read this:

> With contextual actions the situation is more complicated , you still define one menu resource but you implement two separate sets of callbacks , one for contextual action bar and one for floating context menus.

I'm worried now since I only looked at a reference to implement context menus, I didn't read about it much, so I didn't actually target the two things.

I have a context menu with options without icons, only text.

Is this going to be a problem?

I've tested this on API 8 and 17 and 18 but it's the same.

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_rename" android:title="Rename" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_delete" android:title="Delete" />

</menu>
```

**Code**

I'm using `registerForContextMenu(getListView())` so I can handle the view and used:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu , View v , ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.notes_handler_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_rename){
        // do something
    }

    return false;
}
```

Didn't need to put all of the code since there's no problem. I only wanted to know if this is going to cause problems to earlier devices before API 11 or after.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.appabdulmohsen.subjectstracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconsubjecttracker"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.appabdulmohsen.subjectstracker.SubjectList"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name=".Activity_subject_tracking"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >

            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".SubjectList"
                 />

        </activity>


        <service android:name=".Service_reminder"></service>


        <activity 
            android:name=".activity_todialog_notecontent"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            ></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

--

my question is simple , is what I used enough for both api 8 and up ? or do I need to implement other methods ?

Comment: Please post your manifest, as your behavior is driven by that as much as anything, and it will significantly help people in assisting you.

Comment: I've posed what I used to create the context menu , hopefully it'll help

Comment: That is not your manifest. Your manifest is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in your project. If you are using Android Studio, we may also need the `build.gradle` for the app module.

Comment: @CommonsWareI didn't think the mainfest is needed but I've posted it as well , you can take a look again please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm not thinking straight.

You have no code for a contextual action bar, based upon what you have posted. Hence, you will not see a contextual action bar. I don't even know if you have a *regular* action bar -- you probably do, but that would depend upon the definition of `AppTheme`.

Your code will bring up an old-style context menu.

> Is this going to be a problem?

That depends on your definition of "problem". Using a context menu on API Level 15+ devices (i.e., the vast majority of Android devices in use) will look out of date to some people.

Comment: You're not the one that isn't thinking straight , i am :( , I got a little scared when I've read the book , I thought I needed to use both ways of implementing , the one for api less than 11 which is the floating context menu , and the action one for +11 apis , i only implemented the old one " the floating context menu " and I thought it won't run on new devices even though I tested it before on emulators , the book is not stating that it's ok to implement the old one alone.

Comment: @user3880681: Android is pretty good about forwards and backwards compatibility. Any methods that still exist and are not marked as deprecated usually work as well on the latest-and-greatest Android device as they did back when the methods were introduced. In this case, an old-style context menu will work on everything from Android 1.0 onwards. Again, the look-and-feel of this is "retro", which may not help you win any design awards, but it will be perfectly functional.